# UISwipeGestureRecognizer and transition animations

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

I have a UISwipeGestureRecognizer working on my viewcontroller.  If I swipe left or swipe right, I take care of loading another view and displaying it on the screen.

How can I add transitions.  The views are being loaded within a ScrollView which is inside a main ViewController which handles the transitions.

```
        MonoTouch.UIKit.UISwipeGestureRecognizer sgrLeft = new MonoTouch.UIKit.UISwipeGestureRecognizer();
        MonoTouch.UIKit.UISwipeGestureRecognizer sgrRight = new MonoTouch.UIKit.UISwipeGestureRecognizer();

        // add the target to it, we put the instance itself of the controller 
        // and the class instance selector
        sgrLeft.AddTarget(this, new Selector("HandleSwipe"));
        sgrRight.AddTarget(this, new Selector("HandleSwipe"));

        // add the swipe direction, there are 4 of them (left, right, up, down). If other than one swipe is 
        // needed then more recognizers must be defined and added to the view - each for the direction
        sgrLeft.Direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Left; 
        sgrRight.Direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Right; 
        // also assign the delegate
        sgrLeft.Delegate = new Helpers.SwipeRecognizerDelegate();
        sgrRight.Delegate = new Helpers.SwipeRecognizerDelegate();

        // and last, add the recognizer to this view to take actions
        this._scrollView.AddGestureRecognizer(sgrLeft);
        this._scrollView.AddGestureRecognizer(sgrRight);
```

Comment: What have you tried? I cannot see any code that would add subviews anywhere? If you provide that, we could maybe help you.

Comment: You also do not need to use the old style Selector-based swipe handling.   You can just pass a method or delegate to the constructors to the gesture recognizers.